# How to Auto Save Selection in ComboBox into MYSQL in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is it possible to auto save selected item in ComboBox into MYSQL without submit button?

Comment: Yes it is. Now, what's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that by using jquery and ajax.

Jquery get selection box multiple select - $("#combobox_id").val();

ajax - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/